# username and password validation through node.js and sqlite3

Tags: html, node.js, sqlite

I have a table with usernames and passwords that I want to be authenticated when someone enters them on the webpage. If the username and password match, it redirects to a certain page and if they don't then it redirects to a different one.

What I am doing is using the Select statement to only select the row where username and password match of the entered information. So in the resulting query there will either be only one row if the username and password match or none.

The issue I am having is that it only keeps redirecting to the first page. I am assuming it has something to do with the response but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
app.post('/Login', function (req, res, next) {

let sql = `SELECT * FROM Login WHERE (username = "${req.body.username}" AND password = "${req.body.password}")`
var x;

db.all(sql, function (err, rows) {
    rows.forEach(function (row) {
        if (row.username = req.body.username) {
            x = 1;
        }
        else {
            x = 2;
            db.close();
        }
    })
    if (x = 1) {
        res.redirect('/index3');
    }
    else { res.redirect('/index2'); }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside call function in `rows.forEach` and after `rows.forEach`, you have `if` statement and instead of comparison sign `==` or `===`, you have assign sign `=`, I think that a problem.

```
if (row.username === req.body.username) {
  x = 1;
}

if (x === 1) {
    res.redirect('/index3');
}
```

Try this:

```
app.post('/Login', (req, res, next) => {
 let sql = `SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username = "${req.body.username}" AND password = "${req.body.password}"`;
 var x;

 db.all(sql, (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    next(err);
    return;
  }
  if (!rows) {
    res.status(400);
    res.send('Invalid username or password');
    return
  }
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    if (row.username === req.body.username && row.password === req.body.password) {
        x = 1;
    }
    else {
        x = 2;
        db.close();
    }
  })
  if (x === 1) {
    res.redirect('/index3');
  }
  else { res.redirect('/index2'); }
 })
```

**IMPORTANT!** Never ever store users passwords in plaintext. Always hash them before inserting to database. Good hash function for storing password: `bcrypt`.

Comment: @Jess_Rose88 Could you show what data is returned in `rows` variable after query?

Comment: @Jess_Rose88 Did you change your redirect `if` to: if (x == 1) {
        res.redirect('/index3');
    }

Comment: Yes I changed the = to ==. 
If I type in the correct username and password, console.log(rows) displays this    [ { id: '1', username: 'john', password: 'john2017' } ]    
But if I put in the wrong username and password, it does not display anything. However TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined is displayed

Answer (score 0):

you have below issues with your code

A)

```
if (row.username = req.body.username) {
```

it should have been
if (row.username == req.body.username) {// comparision and not assignment

B)

the comparision should be for both username and password

```
if (row.username == req.body.username) {
  x = 1;
}
```

and after that

```
if(x==1){// do something}
else{ //do something else }
```